# MySQL Regex not matching first in comma delimited string of numbers

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and trying to find pages that contain a shortcode and its attributes.

Here's some example content in a page

```
[my-shortcode title="some text" style="grid" 
      post_ids="45724,1786,1889,1927,2613,32856,2976,2898,2372,2059" 
      image_id="61690"]
```

I currently have this MySQL query with a regex. $my_id = a specific number I set.

```
$query = 'SELECT ID,post_content from ' . $wpdb->posts .
    ' where post_type="page"
        and post_content regexp "\[my-shortcode[^\]].*post_ids=\"[^\"].*' .
               $my_id . '[^\"].*\"[^\]].*image_id=\"[0-9].*\"[^\]]?\]"';
```

This seems to work fine except for the first ID in the post_ids attribute. It never matches the first one, only IDs after the first one.

No doubt I'm doing something monumentally obvious but I'm sadly not a regex whizz.

I also appreciate there's other ways I could query the DB in Wordpress but for many other reasons I wont go in to right now this is the way I need to do it.

Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: `[^\"].*` consumes one character - in this case, the first digit of the first number. Did you mean `[^\"]*` (no `.`)?

Comment: That's it! I just knew it would be something idiotically simple. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Be aware, that this will match `post_ids="12345,6789"` for `$my_id = 123`, and is very inefficient. Think about parsing that during saving and putting it into normalized tables so your database doesn't have to do so much heavy lifting on front end requests.

Comment: How can I avoid that match?

Comment: By reading the second half of the comment? :D

Comment: So the only way to avoid that match is by parsing during saving and putting in to a normalized table? Why wouldn't regex be able to match something properly just because there's a comma?

Comment: You can, but your regex will become more complex. You'll have to match for `[^0-9]$my_id[^0-9]`, but then you'll have to add a special case if it's the first or last number in that list etc, and that still doesn't take care of the inefficiency.

Comment: `...post_ids=\"[^\"]*[[:<:]]' . $my_id . '[[:>:]][^\"]*\"...`

Comment: I fully appreciate its not efficient but sometimes urgency supersedes efficiency. I take your point and will look to make it more efficient when time allows.

Comment: MySQL's REGEXP does not handle backslashes as you expect.